# reading multiple files and writing multiple output files

Tags: python

If I have multiple files in a directory C, and I want to write a code reading (automatically) ALL the files and processing each file and then writing an output file for each input file.

For example in directory C i have the following files:

```
aba 
cbr
wos
grebedit
scor
```

Hint: these files are without an obvious extension

Then the program reads these files one by one, process, then write the output in the directory:

```
aba.out
cbr.out
wos.out
grebedit.out
scor.out
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I dont have any idea of how to do this.

Comment: @user2152825 - break down your problem and think about what you do now how to do. Do you know how to get a list of files in a directory? Do you know how to read data from one file? Do you know how to build the name of the output file? Do you know how to write to one output file? Do you know how to construct a loop?  Try one of those tasks, and ask us for specific help when you get stuck. If you don't know how to do **any** of those things, try reading a Python tutorial like [this one](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: yah I know, but I dont know to get files from a directory, such like 500 files to read (I know how to read and write), but I dont how to read many files from a dir automatically.

Comment: @user2152825 Then you should ask that in your question, not all the other stuff that you already understand. If you mean "how do I list all the files in a directory", just ask that.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to direct you to the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Once you're comfortable with file IO in general, here's a basic workflow for you to expand on.

```
def do_something(lines):
    output = []
    for line in lines:
        # Do whatever you need to do.
        newline = line.upper()
        output.append(newline)
    return '\n'.join(output) # 

listfiles = ['aba', 'cbr', 'wos', 'grebedit', 'scor']

for f in listfiles:
    try:
        infile = open(f, 'r')
        outfile = open(f+'.out', 'w')

        processed = do_something(infile.readlines())

        outfile.write(processed)

        infile.close()
        outfile.close()
    except:
        # Do some error handling here
        print 'Error!'
```

If you need to build your list from all the files in a certain directory, use the `os` module.

```
import os
listfiles = os.listdir(r'C:\test')
```

Comment: what if have 500 files and I want to read them Automatically?

Comment: @user2152825 If you want to read all files in a directory automatically, you should put that in your question, not in a comment on someone else's answer. I've edited my answer to help, though.